# Unable to get Selenium Geckodriver to work on Python - Mac OSX High Sierra

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been fighting to get the Selenium Geckodriver for Firefox to work on my mac for some time, and I just can't get it to work.

I have the geckodriver binary in my /usr/local/bin/ directory as the documentation indicates.

When ever I try to execute the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
type(browser)
browser.get('www.google.com')enter code here
```

I get the following error in the Python console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maxmorin/.thonny/BundledPython36/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/Applications/Thonny.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Applications/Thonny.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maxmorin/Google Drive/Support Team Python Code/Max's Projects/Release Readiness/selenium_test.py", line 2, in <module>
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Users/maxmorin/.thonny/BundledPython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 144, in __init__
self.service.start()
  File "/Users/maxmorin/.thonny/BundledPython36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the path to the geckodriver. A way is the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, executable_path=r'/pathTo/geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Make sure that the file is executable:

- chmod +x geckodriver++

**EDIT**

If you don't want to specify the executable_path in your code, you have to add this in your PATH environment variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver
```

Comment: Thanks, that made it work.  Is there an easy way to configure it to be in the PATH location, so that I don't have to put in the executable path every time?